# keyword can't be an expression?

Tags: python

In my code I'm trying to do:

```
if "!variants" in args[0]:
        variants = client.user.party.me.create_variants(
           args[2]=args[3]
        )

        await client.user.party.me.set_outfit(
            asset=args[1],
            variants=variants
        )

        await message.reply('Skin set to' + args[1])
```

And for args[2] it can be numerous things like `clothing_color` or `material` and the only solution I could find is to add different commands for each different args[2], which isn't very efficient and I'd rather shorten the code to 1 command, is:

```
if ("!variants" in args[0]) & ("clothing_color" in args[2]):
        variants = client.user.party.me.create_variants(
            clothing_color=args[3]
        )

        await client.user.party.me.set_outfit(
            asset=args[1],
            variants=variants
        )

        await message.reply('Skin set to' + args[1])

if ("!variants" in args[0]) & ("material" in args[2]):
        variants = client.user.party.me.create_variants(
            material=args[3]
        )

        await client.user.party.me.set_outfit(
            asset=args[1],
            variants=variants
        )

        await message.reply('Skin set to' + args[1])
```

Or is the 2nd method, the only way I can fix this?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a keyword argument dynamically, you need to convert the keyword and value into a dictionary, then pass that using the `**` operator.

```
variants = client.user.party.me.create_variants(**{args[2]: args[3]})
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works up to the 3rd argument, after that it gives me:raise ValueError("occupant JID mismatch")
ValueError: occupant JID mismatch

Comment: That doesn't look like a normal Python error, it's something coming from the `create_variants()` code.

Comment: Two stars unpack a dict: `func(**dict)`

Comment: @VPfB you're suggesting I shouldn't use that or I should, because there is no dict involved.

Comment: @didujusthitdat Yes, you should, like in this answer (after the edit). Argument unpacking like in `func(*args, **kwargs)` is a key feature of Python. Please learn the details if you haven't already. Barmar showed how your question can be solved by creating and unpacking the `kwargs` (without using that name actually) and that is a dict (as a literlal, i.e. `{key: value, ...}`) and needs two stars to unpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`:

```
if "!variants" in args[0] and re.search("clothing_color|material", args[2]):
```

This will return a `Match` object if either words are found and None if not